# MDX showing values of only the best salesmen

Tags: mdx, olap

Let's say I have two simple dimensions:

> Products - with id and name
>
> Salesmen - with id and name

My fact table is named SALES and contains the ids of the abovementioned.

Let's say product X has been sold by salesmen A, B and C.

Product Y has been sold by salesmen B, C, and D

I want to produce a MDX query which would tell me the names of the salesmen who sold both those products. In this case the result would be B and C

My attempt:

```
select {null} on 0,
DESCENDANTS (
[Salesmen].[Name].children
) on 1
FROM [Test]
where (
{
       (
             [Products].[Name].&[X]
       )
,
       (
             [Products].[Name].&[Y]
       )
}
)
```

Comment: provide the proper table structures.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty what do you mean? The table attributes were described in my post

Comment: The `sales table` contains `idproduct and idsalesman` ?

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty Yes

Comment: I can provide mysql query but I am not aware of MDX let me know if this works for you.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty No sorry I need MDX, but thanks for your time

Comment: @Simon should be easy enough - please provide your attempt (even if your attempt is way of the mark just to see your hierarchy structures helps us help you)

Comment: @whytheq Okay I edited the main post with my attempt

Comment: It shows the people who sold one product OR the other ( should be AND)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try nesting `exist` function like this:

```
SELECT 
  {} on 0,
  EXISTS(
    EXISTS(
       {[Salesmen].[Name].MEMBERS}, //<<TRY THIS INSTEAD
       {[Products].[Name].&[X]}
    )
    ,{[Products].[Name].&[Y]}
  )
  ON 1
FROM [Test];
```

Strictly speaking `EXISTS` requires the name of a measures group as it's third argument like this:

```
SELECT 
  {} on 0,
  EXISTS(
    EXISTS(
       {[Salesmen].[Name].MEMBERS} //<<TRY THIS INSTEAD
       ,{[Products].[Name].&[X]}
       ,"Reseller Sales" //<<replace with group name from your cube
    )
    ,{[Products].[Name].&[Y]}
    ,"Reseller Sales" //<<replace with group name from your cube
  )
  ON 1
FROM [Test];
```

An alternative approach is to use a member from the hierarchy `[Measures]` and the functions `NonEmpty` and `Intersect`:

```
SELECT 
  {} on 0,
  INTERSECT(
    NONEMPTY(
       {[Salesmen].[Name].MEMBERS}
       ,([Products].[Name].&[X],[Measures].[SomeMeasureInYourCube])
    )
   ,NONEMPTY(
       {[Salesmen].[Name].MEMBERS}
       ,([Products].[Name].&[Y],[Measures].[SomeMeasureInYourCube])
    )
  )
  ON 1
FROM [Test];
```

The above may well work with a simple tuple of the members of Products only

```
SELECT 
  {} on 0,
  INTERSECT(
    NONEMPTY(
       {[Salesmen].[Name].MEMBERS}
       ,([Products].[Name].&[X])
    )
   ,NONEMPTY(
       {[Salesmen].[Name].MEMBERS}
       ,([Products].[Name].&[Y])
    )
  )
  ON 1
FROM [Test];
```

Comment: This query returns all names of salesmen :(
Edit: shouldnt it be [Salesmen].[Name].children ?

Comment: @Simon I just reused the code you supplied - try  [Salesmen].[Name].children. I edited attempt.

Comment: Ah, right, edited that one out. Anyways, the query returns all salesmen' names nevetheless :(

Comment: ok - do you have a name of a measures group? You add that as the third argument of each exists function. Also if you have a relevent member of the `[Measures]` hierarchy then an alternative approach is possible using NonEmpty. I'll edit.

Comment: My prediction is that the EXISTS function doesn't work with two separate dimension tables.. it works well when I try to specify name of a salesman instead of a product - but I dont know how to solve the problem

Comment: well my only measure group is [Sales count]

Comment: that looks like an actual measure to me rather than a "measure group". You could try using `[Measures].[Sales count]` in the NonEmpty version I've added.

Comment: Hey again! I was just wondering: let's say there are a thousand objects I need to consider - the query would be enormous.. Isn't there any way of modifying the query to suit larger ammounts of products?

Comment: @Simon it will be possible via maybe the member_key properties of these members `[Products].[Name].&[X]` then using a custom measure and the `Filter` function. Post a new question with an attempt using 5 or 6 products and I will try to prototype for you

Comment: @Simon you also need to mark this old question ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27532854/mdx-average-function-counting-on

Comment: All taken care of: please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29514866/mdx-query-best-salesmen-who-sold-all-of-given-products