# MDX query - best salesmen who sold all of given products

Tags: mdx, data-warehouse

Let's say I have two simple dimensions:

> Products - with id and name
>
> Salesmen - with id and name
>   My fact table is named SALES and contains the ids of the abovementioned.

I need to produce a query that will show the names of salesmen who sold all of the given products.

This code solves the problem for two items X and Y:

```
SELECT 
  {} on 0,
  EXISTS(
    EXISTS(
       {[Salesmen].[Name].MEMBERS}, 
       {[Products].[Name].&[X]}
    )
    ,{[Products].[Name].&[Y]}
  )
  ON 1
FROM [Test];
```

The other version is:

```
SELECT 
  {} on 0,
  INTERSECT(
    NONEMPTY(
       {[Salesmen].[Name].MEMBERS}
       ,([Products].[Name].&[X])
    )
   ,NONEMPTY(
       {[Salesmen].[Name].MEMBERS}
       ,([Products].[Name].&[Y])
    )
  )
  ON 1
FROM [Test];
```

However, this method becomes troublesome if the list of given products is large, for example - 100 random products..

Comment: I thought the `EXISTS` version did not work?

Comment: EXISTS works when the two dimensions are of the same hierarchy - in the case of a simple example I made up it is not the case. However, in the more detailed project the exists solution did in fact work (cos the dimensions are in the same hierarchy there) - i'll edit in the other version

Comment: thanks - you're correct (I'd forgotten) that exists is for different hierarchies within the same dimension e.g. say you need to find the towns from the town hierarchy (in geo dimension) that exists for the country Poland, from the country hierarchy (also in geo dimension). The third argument (Measure Group) I mentioned extends Exists so it can function across dimensions.Here is the `MSDN` definition for this function: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144936.aspx

Comment: @whytheq  Thank you! I'll analyse your answer soon! (Btw so far I know that indeed the second member works! But I don't know what you meant typing `>100` and `<500`

Comment: the `>100` and `<500` are important. These are the criteria for the `filter` function to use. So the custom set `[ProdsetA]` will only contain Products that have `MEMBER_Key` that are `<100` whereas the custom set `[ProdsetB]` will only contain Products that have `MEMBER_Key` that are `>500`. You need to use the member values presented to you by my first script to decide what values 100 and 500 should be in your context (...I don't know the key values in your cube so just used 100 and 500 as placeholders)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a property `member_key` for the hierarchy `[Products].[Name]` ? We can test like this:

```
WITH
MEMBER [Measures].[Meas1] AS
 [Products].[Name].CurrentMember.PROPERTIES("KEY ID")
MEMBER [Measures].[Meas2] AS
 [Products].[Name].CurrentMember.MEMBER_Key
MEMBER [Measures].[Meas3] AS
 [Products].[Name].CurrentMember.MEMBERvalue
select
 {
  [Measures].[Meas1]
 ,[Measures].[Meas2]
 ,[Measures].[Meas3]
 } on COLUMNS, 
 [Products].[Name].MEMBERS on ROWS
FROM [Test];
```

Hopefully one of the custom measures gives you a value? I'll assume Meas2 is working (swap to a different one if Meas1 or Meas3 is returning numbers)

```
WITH
  MEMBER [Measures].[Meas2] AS
   [Products].[Name].CurrentMember.MEMBER_Key
  SET [ProdsetA] AS
   FILTER(
     [Products].[Name].MEMBERS
     ,[Measures].[Meas2] <100
   )
  SET [ProdsetB] AS
   FILTER(
     [Products].[Name].MEMBERS
     ,[Measures].[Meas2] >500
   )
SELECT 
 {} on 0,
 INTERSECT(
   NONEMPTY(
      {[Salesmen].[Name].MEMBERS}
      ,[ProdsetA]
   )
  ,NONEMPTY(
      {[Salesmen].[Name].MEMBERS}
      ,[ProdsetB]
   )
 )
 ON 1
FROM [Test];
```

... the `>100` and `<500` are important. These are the criteria for the `filter` function to use. The custom set `[ProdsetA]` will only contain Products that have `MEMBER_Key` that are `<100` whereas the custom set `[ProdsetB]` will only contain Products that have `MEMBER_Key` that are `>500`. You need to use the member values presented to you by the first script to decide what values 100 and 500 should be in your cube context (...I don't know the key values in your cube so just used 100 and 500 as placeholders)

Comment: Thank you! Finally had time to come back to this - it really helped :)